# End after last visual block change

Tags: vim

I frequently highlight some text to indent it

```
<html>
<body>
    <div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

For example, I may <kbd>S-v</kbd> and highlight the `<body>` section, then <kbd>></kbd> to indent it.  After doing this, though the cursor will be at `|<body>`.  Often, I want it to be at `</body>|`.  I can move to the end of the previous block with

```
gv`><Esc>
```

But that seems like a lot of keys for such a simple motion.  Is there any way to move to the *end* of a visual lines after operating on it?

Comment: `c-v` you meant `shift-v`?  also `%` could jump in tag pair, you can on `<body>` press `>%` to indent whole block.  and... in your question, there is a typo in ending `<body>`, `slash` is missing. :) Have you installed any xml plugin? sometimes they are handy.

Comment: Why do you use blockwise visual mode; indenting is linewise, anyway, so `V` would be easier and more natural?!

Comment: @IngoKarkat it's not a big deal, but yes the line-wise does make more sense.  I updated the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no global option that will make *all* operations position the cursor at the end of the selection, but you can override each visual mode commands individually, e.g.:

```
:xnoremap > >`>
```

(This is similar to your manual workaround; note that you don't need to re-enter visual mode with `gv` to move to its end; the mark is kept even after visual mode has been left.)

Comment: Got to love marks! `]` and `>` marks should be come apart of any vimmers workflow. See `:h motions` for more